# Weinre on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket, express, weinre

I am trying to set up [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/) on [heroku](http://www.heroku.com) but I am having some issues.

I manage to build the app, simply by using a package.json with weinre npm dependency and a Procfile that looks like the following

```
web: node_modules/weinre/weinre --httpPort $PORT
```

At first everything seems to work, the client shows up the UI, the JS file loads fine, but the debug does not work and no client ever shows up at the server side.

While looking at the logs, I realized that I keep getting 404 errors for every request that contains /ws/target/* or /ws/client/*

```
2012-05-31T22:37:53+00:00 heroku[router]: GET xxxx.herokuapp.com/target/target-script.js dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=190900
2012-05-31T22:37:36+00:00 heroku[router]: GET xxxx.herokuapp.com/ws/target/t-3 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=9
2012-05-31T22:36:39+00:00 heroku[router]: POST xxxx.herokuapp.com/ws/client/c-1 dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=40ms status=404 bytes=9
```

This setup works localy with no problem.

I also tried the Procilfe with `--boundHost 0.0.0.0` and got the same error. when I use my heroku app domain/subdomain as the host I got `weinre: error running server: Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL` error

If needed, you can checkout the source at the [github repo](https://github.com/felipesabino/weinre-heroku)

https://github.com/felipesabino/weinre-heroku

EDIT:
It is possible that it is related to WebSockets not being supported on Heroku:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#websockets

The weirdest thing is that the same issue happens with PhoneGap's weinre debug page as well
http://debug.phonegap.com/

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you running on the Cedar stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have weinre running on Heroku at the moment but I remember that when I was trying to get it working it was a real nightmare.

This was using the `2.0.0-pre-H0WVARLU-incubating` of weinre so it *may* be a bit different but what I had to do was:

- Modify weinre itself, I had to tell weinre to bind to all hosts, I modified the `cli.coffee` file and I set the `boundHost` to `-all-` as the default
- I commended out the `if remoteAddress` check in `channelManager.coffee` since the address you come in from is remapped through the proxy and was never matching
- Turn on verbose debugging, while you don't actually need this to run it made it a lot easier to trace where errors are happening (and why the requests weren't routing)

My Procfile ended up being very simple as I tried to use weinre as "native" as possible (note the repo contains **only** weinre, it's not a module like you're doing):

```
web: node weinre
```

I left any port changes to be handled by `process.env.PORT`, not passed in from the Procfile

Basically what I found was that weinre really isn't designed to work behind a proxy!

Comment: AWESOME! It is working! I updated the github repo already and I will add some more "heroku specific" instructions on the README file later on! Tks

Comment: FWIW if you need the remote client's IP, you should grab it from the X-Forwarded-For header.

Answer (score 2):

See this pull request https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-weinre/pull/10

Note that no other modifications are needed, Procfile can set the options (like it should) and Weinre is properly used as node module.

package.json (that contains the fix)

```
"dependencies" : {
    "weinre": "https://github.com/downloads/AppGyver/incubator-cordova-weinre/apache-cordova-weinre-2.0.0-pre-H77LBWIW-incubating-bin.tar.gz"
},
```

Procfile

```
web: node_modules/weinre/weinre --httpPort $PORT --boundHost -all- --debug true --verbose true
```

Comment: awesome! did you have the change to test this pull request in heroku's environment?

Comment: Thanks to Matti, weinre was "fixed" so it could run easily on Heroku, and other PaaS's.  I did a blog post on this, at the time: http://pmuellr.blogspot.com/2012/11/weinre-installable-at-heroku-and-behind.html

Answer (score 0):

- Modify weinre itself, I had to tell weinre to bind to all hosts, I modified the cli.coffee file and I set the boundHost to -all- as the default
- I commended out the if remoteAddress check in channelManager.coffee since the address you come in from is remapped through the proxy and was never matching

this two Hints helped a lot on **appfog**, too

Also you need to

- rename weinre to app.js
- require local coffeescript
- assign cli to a variable and execute run direct
- extend cli.coffee - > Port with `process.env.PORT`